# Is it possible to differentate between page refresh and close using the below method?

Tags: javascript, html, django, algorithm, polling

I want to open a popup window on closing the page and not during refresh of the page,

So what i am thinking to do is.

**Clent**

Send ajax request to server every x seconds.

**Server**

```
var timeout=0
var sec=0     
while (sec>timeout)

{

open popup window

sec++;
if(request){

sec=0
}

}
```

**Assumption**

Timeout will be the maximum delay between requests during page rfresh.

**So my questions are:**

1)Will this  technique work?

2)If not Is there any other method to do it?

3)If It works what is optimal value for Timeout variable(in seconds)

4)How can i implement a small example in django is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of asking us why don't you  try yourself?

Comment: @AmGate But i don't know how to make ajax request to server every x seconds...Can u give a link or provide a example?

Comment: Try this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and for giving time based request use the setTimeinterval method or setTimeout method

Answer (score 0):

Just think for a simple solution. Why are you going for the complex solution?
The simple way to get popup on page close is to just define the "**window.onunload**" event as shown below.

```
window.onunload = function(){

//Code to display Popup

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ya i know about it. But onunload cannot differentiate between page refresh and close.So i am trying to differentiate that using this solution(don't know this works or not).